# error Evaluating classifier Train and test dataset are not compatible

Tags: machine-learning, svm, weka, smo

I am getting error while running SMO model on test dataset in weka

> Problem Evaluating classifier Train and test dataset are not
>   compatible. Class index differ: 3 != 0

Training dataset format

```
mean,variance,label
54.3333333333,1205.55555556,five
3.0,0.0,five
31739.0,0.0,five
3205.5,4475340.25,one
```

Test dataset format

```
mean,variance
3.0,0.0
257.0,0.0
216.0,14884.0
736.0,0.0
```

I trained the training dataset and want to get labels for the test dataset. Why I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The test dataset should have identical structure to the training data.  In your case you should add a column to the end called "label".  Then, you need to assign some value to the label.  This could be simply a question mark "?" to indicate the true label is unknown.